# Java - OR operator in an equals expression

Tags: java, logic, logical-operators

Would somebody be able to explain the following lines of Java code to me?

```
if (a == b){
theArray[element1][element2] = theArray[element1][element2 - 1] || theArray[element1][element2]
}
```

theArray is a Boolean, 2-dimensional array.

I have never seen a logical or `(||)` used in an equals expression.
How could the array element equal something OR something? I would very much appreciate some help with understanding how array elements could be equal to something OR something...

Comment: `theArray` seems to be of 2d boolean array which would explain the rest.

Comment: It is a 2D Boolean Array, but I still don't understand that. I have edited my question to reflect that

Comment: As the 2d array contains boolean values, so it is valid to do, `theArray[1][1] = theArray[1][0] || theArray[1][0]` assuming `element1 =1` and `element2 =1`

Comment: In this case, this will work if an element is boolean data, example element[0][0] = element[0][1] || element[0][2], i.e.: element[0][0] = false || true. This will give false you need to take a look truth table. In order to use that operator

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Now I understand (I think). Is it doing the same as `theArray[element1][element2] = (theArray[element1][element2 - 1] || theArray[element1][element2]`);`

Comment: Thank you both for hashing out a solution -- perhaps fill it out as an Answer for myself and other users who might have similar dumb moments like me ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I have never seen a logical or (||) used in an equals expression*

Firstly, there is no `equals expression` here, it is an assignment.

What makes this confusing is the lack of *brackets*

Consider

```
theArray[element1][element2] = (theArray[element1][element2 - 1] || theArray[element1][element2]);
```

which may equate to something like

```
theArray[element1][element2] = (true || false);
```

Comment: Applying parenthesis is not really required though it makes code more readable but it can't happen that first the assignment happens with first two elements and then it is ORed with right most element as that would not make any sense in java.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Thank you for your additional comment.  *it makes code more readable*  - yes this is really the crux of the question isn't it.

Comment: Yes, even though my comment was for you but it extends to OP too :) That it can't happen that assignment happens first and then OR operation in case OP had the same confusion. And since java supports it, it shouldn't have been considered other way round. Although to make code clear, one should preferably use parenthesis around such expressions.